# Windows authentication with Docker IIS using GMSA

Tags: docker, windows-authentication

I need your help here on setting up Win authentication with IIS in docker.
I have configured properly gMSA account, nltest /query returns success results.
Still while accessing my application it asks for credentials.

SPN with HTTP service has been added in GMSA

**Additional info: (Inside container)**

1. Anonymous and Windows authentication is enabled
2. App pool is running under LocalSystem
3. Hostname of the continer is same as gMSA.
4. net user username /do returns correct results
5. nltest /query and /parent domain returns correct results

Please help me here.

warm regards,
Suhas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Go to "Internet Options"
2. Go to "Security" tab
3. Click on "Trusted Site"
4. Click on the "Sites" button to add your website.
5. The website must be "https://www.example.com" format with https.
6. Click ok, but do not exit the Internet Options yet.
7. Go down and click on "Custom level..." button
8. Scroll all the way down to "User Authentication"
9. Select the radio button for "Automatic login with current user name and password"
10. Finally click OK for everything until you exit the Internet Options.

Now you can try to access your container website.